# Пробелма авторизации EWS Managed Api через сайт на asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exchange, ews

Пытаюсь организовать работу с собраниями (appointments) через сайт на asp.net mvc 5 с помощью EWS Managed api 2.
Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог создать собрание от своего имени через веб. В VS при отладке с `UseDefaultCredentials = true` отрабатывает и создает. После деплоя в ISS:

"No mailbox with such guid" или "The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML"

С конкретными `Credentials = new WebCredentials("usename", "pass", "domain")` на ISS отрабатывает, но тогда все события будут от имени одного лица.
winsows авторизация на сайте включена. сайт локальный, пользователи все доменные. либо как то подменить `appointment.Organizer`, если оставлять конкретные `Credentials`.

Answer (score 0):

Я столкнулся с той же проблемой, что и на следующем форуме: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/e54c217f-28ff-4626-8ce8-a1242081f4d1/

(По существу, дополнительные символы были предварительно отложены и добавлены к возвращенному XML-адресу, вызвав ошибку выше)

Если какая-либо помощь - удаление и повторное создание виртуального каталога EWS не облегчили проблему.

Я считаю, что, возможно, наш балансировщик нагрузки F5 или некоторое промежуточное устройство вставляют дополнительные символы в начале или конце XML.

Когда я изменил свой код на: service.Url = новый Uri («https: //192.168.x.x/EWS/Exchange.asmx»);

(По существу, используя внутренний IP-адрес нашего сервера обмена), запрос работал просто отлично. Так что что-то вне обмена - это искажение XML

Comment: поправил ссылку. "No mailbox with such guid" никуда не делось.

Answer (score 0):

No mailbox with such guid

Эта ошибка обычно вызвана нелицензированной учетной записью почтового ящика. Убедитесь, что все миграционные почтовые ящики лицензированы в Office 365.

Если учетной записи почтового ящика была назначена лицензия, и ошибка сохраняется, это обычно вызвано значением, отличным от Null, в атрибуте msExchMailboxGuid учетной записи почтового ящика.

По умолчанию при синхронизации пользователя из локальной среды, в которой есть назначенный ему почтовый ящик, будет также синхронизироваться значение атрибута msExchMailboxGuid. Присвоение лицензии Office 365 в этом случае не приведет к созданию почтового ящика.

Выполните следующие действия, чтобы подтвердить эту проблему в Office 365:

Войдите в офис арендатора Office 365 с помощью учетной записи глобального администратора и перейдите на страницу администратора.
На панели «Активные пользователи» найдите адрес электронной почты пострадавшего пользователя.
Нажмите на имя пользователя и посмотрите в настройках Mail.
Сообщение, связанное с почтовым ящиком, будет следующим: «Внутренний почтовый ящик этого пользователя не был перенесен в Exchange Online. Почтовый ящик Exchange Online будет доступен после завершения миграции».

Comment: эээ у меня exchange 2016. да и консольное приложение с ews работает, на сервере в том числе. не работает через веб с default credentials